# gulp-image-optimization build gives error

Tags: gulp, gulp-imagemin, imagemin

My Node and Npm Vesrions are below

node v6.9.1
npm  v3.10.9

My code is

```
'use strict';
const gulp = require('gulp');
const imageop = require('gulp-image-optimization');

let dir = {
    srcImages: 'public/wps/source/images',
    build: 'public/wps/build/'
};

const config = {
    src: dir.srcImages + '/**/*',
    dest: dir.build + 'images/'
};

gulp.task('img-prod', function (cb) {
   gulp.src(config.src).pipe(imageop({
           optimizationLevel: 5,
           progressive: true,
           interlaced: true
       })).pipe(gulp.dest(config.dest)).on('end', cb).on('error', cb);
});
```

When i do gulp build it throws an error

internal/child_process.js:289
  var err = this._handle.spawn(options);
                         ^

> TypeError: Bad argument
>       at TypeError (native)
>       at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:289:26)
>       at exports.spawn (child_process.js:380:9)
>       at Imagemin._optimizeJpeg (/Users/sureshraju/xxx/Wps/web-pres/node_modules/image-min/imagemin.js:126:12)
>       at Imagemin.optimize (/Users/sureshraju/xxxx/Wps/web-pres/node_modules/image-min/imagemin.js:57:26)
>       at module.exports (/Users/sureshraju/xxxx/Wps/web-pres/node_modules/image-min/imagemin.js:179:21)
>       at /Users/sureshraju/xxxx/Wps/web-pres/node_modules/gulp-image-optimization/index.js:38:17
>       at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)

Comment: I haven't tested this, but try to limit your glob to only images, not all files.

Comment: Am using Images alone...not all files

Comment: `/**/*` means all files.

Comment: My Image folder contains sub-folders. To include all of those i made it like that

Answer (score 0):

Do you have svg files in your source directory?
I have just been getting the exact same problem in a project I have picked up from someone else.

I omitted svg files from the glob and the task then ran without errors.